# pipe output of grep as an argument to a bash script

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

`script.sh` takes two files as arguments, and it calls a python script that opens them and does further processing on these files:

```
script.sh file1.txt file2.txt
```

I would like to remove all lines from file1.txt that start with #.

```
grep -v '^#' file1.txt
```

I tried the following but it fails :

```
script.sh $(grep -v '^#' file1.txt) file2.txt
```

How can I pipe the output of grep as the first file argument of script.sh?

Comment: `script.sh <(grep -v '^#' file1.txt) file2.txt`

Answer (score 3):

```
script.sh <(grep -v '^#' file1.txt) file2.txt
```

Command substitution as you had it, `$()`, will insert the output from the grep command verbatim as arguments to `script.sh`. In contrast, to quote the bash man page:

> Process substitution allows a process's input or output to be referred to using a filename.  It takes the form of <(list) or >(list).  The process list is run asynchronously, and its input or output appears as a filename. This  filename is passed as an argument to the current command as the result of the expansion.

and

> If the <(list) form is used, the  file  passed as an argument should be read to obtain the output of list.

So, my understanding is that when you use `$()`, the output of your grep command is substituted into the final statement with a result something like:

```
script.sh contents of file1 without comments \n oops newline etc file2.txt
```

But when you use `<()`, the grep command is run and the output goes into a named pipe or temporary file or some equivalent, and the name of that "file" is substituted into your statement, so you end up with something along the lines of

```
script.sh /dev/fd/temp_thing_containing_grep_results file2.txt
```

Comment: Do you know why process substitution '<()' works here and not command substitution '$()'?

Comment: @xdhmoore Using your suggested command, I get the following error: /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected. I tried running the script with ./script.sh, but it did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MM added some explanation to the extent of my understanding. Corrections welcome.

Comment: @Marc it works for the toy test case I came up with. Are you putting a space between `<(` by any chance? There shouldn't be a space there.

Comment: @xdhmoore No, there is no space there.

Comment: @Marc sh =/= bash. Change your script's shebang to `#!/bin/bash`, or if sh is an older version of bash on your computer, update it.

Comment: Agreed it does sound like the error is a result of running `sh` instead of `bash`.